# Eddington-Finkelstein and extension of the Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, geodesics

I'm trying to understand how the Eddington–Finkelstein coordinates lead to the extension of the "original Schwarzschild spacetime" (which I understand to be the region with $r > 0$ in the standard Schwarzchild coordinates).

In [Blau's lecture notes](http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/GRLecturenotes.html), above the equation (27.113) there is a paragraph saying

> In the above $(v, r)$ coordinate system [the in-going Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates] we can cross the event horizon only on future-directed paths, not on past-directed ones, and only in the direction of decreasing $r$.

and then the note moves onto motivating the extension of the Schwarzschild spacetime.

But if I pick an *in-coming null geodesic*, and I reverse its arrow (therefore it's past-directed), wouldn't it **cross the horizon**, and move in the direction of **increasing $r$**? **I wonder if I'm misunderstanding the text?**

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, and I believe the phrase is just a bit poorly written. The exact argument you gave provides an example of how one can cross the event horizon in the direction of increasing $r$ by following a past-directed null geodesic. I believe Blau meant that no one can cross the event horizon in a future-directed geodesic in the direction of increasing $r$ (i.e., no one can escape the black hole).